# Can you create and call statics inside a module in VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

My module is a page directory to strongly type pages in a large ASP.Net webforms application using VB.Net.

```
Public Module PageDirectory
        Public Module Sub
             Private _subDirectory As String = "/sub/"

             Public ReadOnly Property MyPage As String
                 Get
                    Return _subDirectory + "mypage.aspx"
                 End Get
             End Property
        End Module
End Module
```

I want to declare it like this on a page `Response.Redirect(PageDirectory.Sub.MyPage)`
but i can't seem to get a module inside a module. My assumption was that a module is the equivalent to a c# static.

Answer (score 0):

Module already says that everything in the class is static, that's why you can't have modules inside of modules.

If you want specific class member be static, you use "shared" on that class member.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7825002w(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think I've worked out the answer. But unsure if its the 'right' way to do this.

```
Public Module PageDirectory
        Private _subDirectory As String = "/sub/"

        Public Structure SubStruct
             Public Shared ReadOnly Property MyPage As String
                 Get
                    Return _subDirectory + "mypage.aspx"
                 End Get
             End Property
        End Module
End Module
```

Comment: Change both the module _**and**_ the structure to classes. Then you're doing it right.